# Anaconda Powershell Install Not Launching Jupyter Notebook

Tags: powershell, anaconda

PS script to download and extract anaconda:

```
$uri = "https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Windows-x86_64.exe"
$outFile = "C:\Users\shan.lodh\Downloads\anaconda.exe"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile $outFile 
Start-Process -FilePath $outFile -Wait -PassThru -ArgumentList '/S', '/v','/qn', `
   '/InstallationType=AllUsers', '/AddToPath=1', '/RegisterPython=1', '/D=C:\Users\shan.lodh\anaconda'
```

Above works fine (takes a while though) and the following confirms conda and python have been installed:

```
> conda activate base (#let's not worry about running in base here) 
> python
Python 3.8.5 ...
```

However if I try:

```
> conda activate base
> jupyter notebook
```

Nothing happens, but checking port 8888 against PID shows python.exe is running at this port (as it should be) but the notebook is not being rendered. Any suggestions? Thanks

**edit**: same happens using anaconda cmd or PS clients